# How to run blender video editor on a weak graphics card?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Preview area of blender video editor is always white (blank) no matter what the picture or the video is.
[image]

After a little research, I found out it's due to my old OpenGL:
[image]

I can't afford to buy a good graphics card and I really need this video editor. My graphics card was able to run many video editing software such as sony vegas...etc. It was also able to run 3D max and Cinema 4D. The only withdraw is that the rendering process is slow. So I feel like my card is able to run blender's video editor and it's just a bug but I don't know how to tweak or fix it.

I'd like answers with creative ideas. I wouldn't like the answer to be like *You can't*.

Comment: Try older Blender versions

Comment: I used to run 2.6x with a 64MB Geforce 4 MX, set your monitor bit depth to 16bit or try a lower the resolution. Maybe make blenders window smaller instead of full screen.

Comment: @WhatAMesh I tried four different versions but still have the same issue. The versions are: 2.76 & 2.67 & 2.59 & 2.48

Comment: @sambler I tried it everything except the 16bit cuz the only option was 32bit. Still have the same issue. I think I was able to set it to 16bit in the past. I'll try to find/Enable this option.

Comment: Turn down the render resolution i.e 25%. Lower the proxy render setting (video view properties). Lower the memory usage of the machine by other apps so it is available to Blender.

Comment: I used to run 2.48 on very very old hardware and like you say, the only issue was how slow it was. This *should* work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having your exact hardware, it is really difficult to give an exact answer, or even good suggestions. You didn't even describe your pc specs or your card model, drivers version. It could help.

But I think you could, as a last resort, try a software opengl emulation. It won't be performant, it won't be fast and it could have (other) glitches, but at least you could try.

How? In simple terms, usually blender relies on the (usually much powerful) opengl hardware implementation but there are software implementation that are run by your cpu, and they could support better opengl levels, hopefully better than your gpu or driver.

The most used, I think is Mesa (https://mesa3d.org/) and you should build (compile) it to obtain a dll. But you can also find some .dll pre-built around... just be careful about the source you're relying on!

Here is a developer's thread that explains roughly how to do this (note the link suggested is now dead!):

https://developer.blender.org/T43077

> Download opengl32.dll from
>   http://download.blender.org/ftp/incoming/softwaregl/ and put it into
>   the same folder as the blender.exe. This will switch blender to fully
>   software opengl mode, avoiding possible issues with
>   driver/configuration

I found a steam thread that has working links, apparently

> for 32bit
>   http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win32/opengl32.dll
>   and for 64
>   http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win64/opengl32.dll
>   once downloaded just put in the directory of blender

https://steamcommunity.com/app/365670/discussions/0/598198356178829559/

See this thread also

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/138029-OpenGL32-dll

I used this approach once (on linux, on thinkpad R60 with a crappy intel card) and it kinda worked, although the most complex functions in blender had issues, but I used this way until I had a new pc, with a much better card, to use the (at the time) newest blender versions... So, you have to try, and maybe report here your findings, to help others!

Good luck!

Comment: Download opengl32.dll from and put it into the same folder as the blender.exe. This works for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Update your video drivers, disable everything that you can in the User Preferences (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>) especially anisotropic filtering, multisampling, and make sure you try GLSL image drawing mode.

[image]

That's about it. If it works it works if it doesn't, then it doesn't.

You cannot work with video if you cannot afford good hardware - no amount of wishing is going to change that.