# Blender is so laggy?

Tags: system

My graphics card is not good but thanks to the answer in this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118936/how-to-run-blender-video-editor-on-a-weak-graphics-card), I was able to run Blender.

The interface is very laggy. When I click anywhere it takes about 0.5 to 1 second to show the menu or do the necessary action.

Now, I have Core 2 due (2.33 GHz) and 3 GB of RAM. Graphics card is intel 384 MB.

I think the interface has nothing to do with the graphics card so why is it so laggy? My PC is able to run any other software's interface. I expect that later, I'll have issues with rendering speed because of my old card. But why do I have issues now with the interface? It's nothing to do with Segments, Materials, textures, lighting,...etc.

**Edit:** I'll try to add more details. Maybe it could help:

When I delete the Opengl32.dll file, the interface of blender works smoothly but I face some issues while rendering.

When I keep the Opengl32.dll file, rendering is good but the interface is very slow.

Is there any code or plug-in that I can use so that blender uses the Opengl32.dll file or the graphics card while rendering only. Otherwise, it should use the normal RAM and CPU for loading and running the interface and the modeling mode.

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Comment: Blender UI is completely drawn by opengl, and that makes it so versatile. That unfortunately makes it also very slow in your case. I've been there, as I said in my answer to "that question". The only satisfying solution could be a new card, or (unlikely) better drivers, imho.

Comment: "*I think the interface has nothing to do with the graphics card*" That is wrong. Most applications don't but Blender does

Comment: But when I delete the opengl32.dll file, the interface works very smoothly. Is there any way to enable/run the opengl32.dll file while rendering only? Otherwise, I'd like to disable it.